# Twilio send voice message

Tags: android, twilio

Is it possible to send **voice message** using [twilio](http://www.twilio.com)? I need to record voice and send it to specific users from android.

I can send text message using [Twilio send message API](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You'd first need to record a message - see [docs/api/rest/recording](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording) and [docs/quickstart/php/twiml/record-caller-leave-message](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/twiml/record-caller-leave-message) for that.

Then, you'll need to play that recording back - see [docs/api/rest/making-calls](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) and [docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request) for making calls. The previously mentioned [docs/quickstart/php/twiml/record-caller-leave-message](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/twiml/record-caller-leave-message) should also help with playing back the recording.

Some of this might be relevantly documented in the HowTo Voicemail documentation at [docs/howto/voicemail](http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/voicemail).

You might also be able to do some/all of this with [Twilio Client](http://www.twilio.com/client) as opposed to [Twilio Voice](http://www.twilio.com/voice).